# Modeling a constraint such that a set of binary decision variables do not equate to 1 simultaneously

Tags: modeling, integer-programming, constraint, binary-variable, logical-constraints

I would like to seek some advice on modeling the following logical condition:

I would like to ensure that a group of binary variables do not equate to 1 simultaneously, i.e., $\omega_{1}=1, \omega_{2}=1,\cdots,\omega_{n}=1$ is unaccepted.

On the other hand, the values for $\omega_{1},\omega_{2},\cdots,\omega_{n}$ can take any permutation of 0s and 1s, e.g. $\omega_{1}=1,\omega_{2}=1,\cdots,\omega_{n}=0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about
$$\omega_1 + \cdots + \omega_n \le n-1 $$

This way, at most all variables but one of them can take value $1$ simultaneously.

In the context of knapsack problems, if each variable models the selection of a given item and that the sum of the weights of the items exceed the knapsack capacity, these inequalities are called *cover inequalities*.

Answer (score 8):

@Kuifje's formulation is correct.  Here's a somewhat automatic derivation via conjunctive normal form:
$$
\lnot \bigwedge_{i=1}^n \omega_i \\
\bigvee_{i=1}^n \lnot \omega_i \\
\sum_{i=1}^n (1 - \omega_i) \ge 1 \\
\sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i \le n-1 \\
$$

Comment: Thanks @RobPratt, these conjunctive normal forms are always very helpful.